# where can i find a monospace hebrew characters font

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, font-face

i know this may seem a question that was similar asked before, but i am searcing for over 5 hours now and i just can't find any monospaced hebrew charcters font, not a single one.

i need this font for my html site (built with angular.js).

i am using like this:

```
  <style>
@font-face { font-family: myhebrew; src: url('DejaVuSansMono.TTF'); } 

</style>
```

my problem is that i have data that is showed inside 4 tables that are alligned.
my problem is that sometimes the text inside the  elements may be longer than the width i declared. in these cases i need to cut the left characters. the problem is that i don't see any other choice than to use monospaced font so i could calculate when to remove the left characters.

please save me. i have tried many fonts like dejaVuMono but nothing worker with hebrew characters.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Monospace fonts that contain Hebrew characters include Free Mono in the [GNU Freefont](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/freefont/) package and [Everson Mono Unicode](http://www.evertype.com/emono/).

Answer (score 1):

There are old fonts like Courier that will support monospace in Hebrew, but they are not updated. I tried Cousine font as @alex suggested but it has a flat look.

After some digging, I found that [FreeMono](https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/freemono.font) has support for Hebrew, and is more rounded. see example:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FreeMono';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: 
     local('FreeMono'), 
     url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/16387/FreeMono.woff') format('woff');
}

pre {
  font-family: 'FreeMono', sans-serif;
  font-size: 6vw;
}
```

```html
<pre>
גינון זיגוג
חפש סתם אהב
יוון או יפן 

נצץ מסת זהב
בז מצץ תנסה
מסבנת זה צץ
זהב צץ תנמס

1234567890 
mono=space
 . , : ; ! 
ספייס=מונו
לספורעדעשר

ושאבתם
   מים
 בששון 
ממעיני
הישועה

טון  פרק   אם
שי לחג דף כעך 
זהב  צץ  תנמס

פםטארק   ןו
ףךלחעכדש  י
ץתצמהבס גנז
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found monospace hebrew characters in the cousine font family.